# What would a realistic wood-eating animal look like?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, fauna

For context:

- The location is Earth, several tens of millions of years ago.
- A rat-like mammal began to adapt to digest wood.
- Slowly, they're growing bigger and bigger, and they'll fill in the stead of elephants.

What would this animal look like, realistically?

Comment: A very large beaver?

Comment: You already said they're rat-like, so they'd look rat-like. What's the question?

Comment: they START out rodent like.

Comment: They'd have characteristics enabling them to get wood inside them and a big enough stomach to digest it. We couldn't possibly reasonably predict anything beyond that - so this question seems unfocused as the number of potential things it could "look like" is pretty broad. How shall we determine what's a best answer except opinion?

Comment: If there are enough wood-eating creatures, then the distribution of trees and forests will presumably be pretty different too. Wood is successful partly because animals don't eat it.

Comment: Like *Triceratops*.

Comment: Termites have bacteria that help them digest wood. Maybe something this large is a symbiotic host to termites or something like that which then contains bacteria to digest the wood.

Comment: @Atog the easiest solution of course is to just eat the termites...

Comment: So maybe it looks like an anteater? With beaver teeth too?

Comment: A giant rabbit maybe ? Or a giant camel, in the winter season ? I'll have to vtc along, this has several very *realistic* answers, all equally valid ! Needs focus/improvement !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Giant Beavers:

While your rodents actually eat wood, the adaptations allowing beavers to chew wood make them a good candidate for the appearance of your wood-eater. the prehistoric [giant beaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castoroides#:%7E:text=Castoroides%2C%20or%20giant%20beaver%2C%20is,the%20rest%20of%20its%20range.) is the best starting point.

These big boys were modified from the classic beaver form in that their hind legs were likely shorter relative to the front, and the tails aren't likely to have been paddle shaped. The dentition is the most distinctive feature, allowing the chewing of solid wood.

But a wood-eating rodent wouldn't have to be all that different from an actual elephant. All the adaptations allowing the elephant to grab and lift trees allows them to eat the woody parts of stems and bushes. Slightly more beaver-like teeth would allow them to chew solid wood.

[image: Giant beaver]

Beyond that, size would matter. These creatures likely digest wood in a matter similar to a [termite](https://sciencing.com/how-do-termites-digest-wood-13406469.html), with a symbiotic organism of some kind doing the actual final digestion. Large amounts of slowly digesting dense cellulose would mean there would be a lot of food in process at any given time. Those big, powerful teeth are probably also a defensive tool to keep predators away from big, slow bodies. A grinding organ internally allowing pulverization of wood to fine pulp would probably be needed, akin to a gizzard.

Answer (score 5):

[Hyraxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyrax) and elephants have a common ancestor. Here's an arabian rock hyrax:

[image: Arabian rock hyrax]

(image credit: [Vauxford](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arabian_Rock_Hyrax_(Procavia_capensis_jayakari)_(Itching)_(CWPG).jpg))

They diverged about 60 million years ago, and the animals descended from that ancestor include elephants, manatees and hyraxes. These are all pretty different looking animals, which should tell you that over evolutionarily interesting timescales you can get major changes in size, shape and appearance.

> what would this animal look like, realistically ?

It'll be a [tetrapod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrapod) with dentition suitable for gnawing and crushing branches, and a digestive system adapted to break down large quantities of lignin. Beyond that it could look like more or less *anything*.

There are some good reasons that big herbivores tend to eat leaves and thin branches though... not only are they more easily digested, and contain a wider range of nutrients, but they also tend to grow back relatively quickly. Trees can recover from being gnawed off at ground level (see modern human practises like pollarding and [coppicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppicing#Natural_occurrence), for example) but regrowth is necessarily much slower.

Even beavers don't bother eating trees, because eating pretty much anything else provides much more reward and is much easier. Boring beetles and worms and insect larvae eat the soft fleshy bits of trees between the heartwood and the outer bark. Trees rich in lignin have been about for [over 300 million years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous), and even over that vast span of time it seems that herbivorous macrofauna has always preferred eating leaves. It has taken less time for plants to evolve [flowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowering_plant) and vertebrates to [evolve flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterosaur) in [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeopteryx) different [ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat)! The lesson to be learned here is that if your lifestyle is any more energetic than a [shipworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipworm), you should probably find a more nutritious and easily digestible diet.

(the latter, by the way, use symbiotic bacteria to help digest wood. your wood-eater might take a similar approach, possibly using a large multi-chambered stomach akin to the [ruminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruminant) digestive system)

Comment: edited my question to fit the time needed